# How to obfuscate the output file before buliding the NuGet package?

Tags: asp.net, build, asp.net-core, nuget, obfuscation

I have:

A project on .NET Core. The project builds with MyGet service https://www.myget.org I didn't decide which obfuscator I should use yet (so if you know good one, please advise it to me).

I should:

Add a task to project, this task should obfuscate output file before NuGet package building and deploing it into Feed. I want to use the build-service [build-service](https://www.myget.org) so this obfuscation task should work on this service, not on local PC only.

How can I create this task?